# Move folder svn folder , ensuring I get co-workers update?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have to move a svn folder to another location . I have done it as follows:

To move a file or set of files using Tortoise SVN, right-click-and-drag the target files to their destination and release the right mouse button. The popup menu will have a SVN move versioned files here option.

However , the changes are local and my co-workers constantly need to commit in that folder.
I am not getting their updates . How do i ensure that i can get their updates on my moved folder

Answer (score 0):

You won't get their updates until you commit your changes **and** your co-workers update their working copies and commit their changes to the moved folder.

If you have a lot of people committing frequently to these folders that need to be moved, it may be easiest for everyone if you call for a brief stoppage, have everyone commit their changes, perform the move, then have everyone update their working copies and resume work.